# How to create an soft link to a specific django admin table

Tags: django, jinja2

How do I create a link to a django admin table using the `url` tag?

I have been trying to create a link to a django admin table. This table was registed in the app called `store` inside a module called `admin.py`, and was refering to a model called Products.

It's possible to access this table at link `/admin/store/products/`.

I would like to know how do I create a link dynamically without writing the hardcoded link in the template.

Answer (score 1):

When you register a class that inherits from the `django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin` class, Django registers the associated views with the following pattern:

- path name to main dashboard table: `admin:<APP_NAME>_<CLASS_NAME>_changelist`
- path name to create form: `admin:<APP_NAME>_<CLASS_NAME>_add`

Thus, to create a link to the page described in the question would be as follows:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:store_products_changelist' %}"> Link </a>
```

If you need to know the pattern of another specific path name, take a look at the `AdminSite` class in the `django.contrib.admin.sites` module.